# revitapi ironpython ToRoom returns "indexer # object"

Tags: ironpython, revit-api

in revit api i am trying to access the ToRoom / FromRoom properties for doors.
the simplified code snippet in ironpython:

```
fc = FilteredElementCollector(doc)
doors = fc.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Doors).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()

for door in doors:
    froom = door.FromRoom
```

my result is an "indexer # object at 0x0000000000035" 
how can i access the room object from here?

Comment: I am afraid I do not know the answer to your question. It looks all right to me. However, your call to ToElements is unnecessary and inefficient. The filtered element collector itself is already iterable. ToElements creates a copy of the entire collection. Here is a detailed discussion of the similar inefficiency of ToElementIds: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/12/toelementids-performance.html

Comment: please note that the same question is also discussed in the revit api discussion forum thread http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api/toroom-fromroom-python-issue/m-p/6507328

Comment: Jeremy thank you for the hint pertaining the filtered element collector.

Answer (score 3):

This is an IronPython / funky Revit API issue. Basically, the way `FromRoom` is defined, it can be either a property or an indexed property. See the [API documentation for FromRoom](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/2b41a232-8cc9-e2bf-8e47-dd95eaf25275.htm).

The "indexer" you get is the second version of `FromRoom` - it takes a `Phase` as its argument. So you can basically do this:

```
phase = list(doc.Phases)[0]
room = door.FromRoom[phase]
```

Since the documentation for `FromRoom` says it returns

> The "From Room" set for the door or window in the last phase of the project.

You probably actually want to do this:

```
phase = list(doc.Phases)[-1]  # retrieve the last phase of the project
room = door.FromRoom[phase]
```

I was not able to figure out how to get hold of the other version of `FromRoom`...

Comment: thanks, thomas! the developer discovered the same thing and shared his working solution using the same approach you recommend in the Revit API discussion forum http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api/toroom-fromroom-python-issue/m-p/6507328

Comment: And how did you know to do that exactly .. ? I would have never guessed from the Revit API description that this is the correct way to use the FromRoom property. room.get_Parameter(DB.BuiltInParameter.ROOM_NAME).AsString() if you are after the Name as per this [link](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/exception-system-missingmemberexception-name-amp-amp-indexer-has/td-p/8138318)

Answer (score 0):

Daren, thank you for your contribution!
after jeremy's answer I examined the same approach.
here is the code snippet

```
fc = FilteredElementCollector(doc)
doors = fc.OfCategory( BuiltInCategory.OST_Doors ).WhereElementIsNotElementType()

phases = doc.Phases

phase = phases[phases.Size - 1]

for door in doors:
    try:
        froom = door.FromRoom[phase].Id
    except:
        froom = -1
    try:
        troom = door.ToRoom[phase].Id
    except:
        troom = -1

    TaskDialog.Show("Revit","%s, %s" %(froom, troom))`
```