# calling specific property overload in C# from Python

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to call a specific property overload (not method overload) on an object constructed in C#, from IronPython. Here are the two overloads available:

[image]

When I call it like so:

```
famInst.FromRoom
```

it returns an object `IronPython.Runtime.Types.ReflectedIndexer`. When I try to use the `Overloads` it throws an exception:

```
famInst.FromRoom.Overloads[]()
```

it throws an exception `"unexpected object "]""`.

Is there a way to specify the overload for this property?

Comment: please give me the link to that documentation

Comment: Try this: http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/ea6bc434-d938-d0e5-ecc3-33e37dbf1d1b.htm

Comment: ok, it looks like there is an issue with the Revit API and IronPython implementation of it. This was already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001482/revitapi-ironpython-toroom-returns-indexer-object It seems that there is no answer to it just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as property overloading in C#. What you are asking about is called an **indexer**. Here is an example of an indexer:

```
public class Foo
{
    SomeObject this[int index]
    {
        // The get accessor.
        get
        {
            // return the value specified by index
        }

        // The set accessor.
        set
        {
            // set the value specified by index
        }
    }
}
```

That means I can treat `Foo` like an array as follows:

```
var f1 = new Foo();
SomeObject someObj = f1[1];
```

In your case the documentation has this:

```
public Room this[
    Phase phase
] { get; }
```

What that means is that `FamilyInstance` has an indexer which takes a `Phase` instance and returns a `Room`. So you would use it like this:

```
// If phase is abstract then new the concrete type. I am not familiar with revit API
var somePhase = new Phase(); 
famInst[somePhase];
```

Or, since it is a named indexer, you can do this:

```
famInst.FromRoom[somePhase];
```

The other one is a plain property and documented like this:

```
public Room FromRoom { get; }
```

You can only access that property but you cannot set it like this:

```
Room room = famInst.FromRoom;
```

So basically, and indexer allows you to treat a class like an array even though the class is not an array. In this case `FamilyInstance` can be treated like an array. There are many types in .NET which have indexers, for example, `String` has an indexer like this:

```
public char this[int index] { get; }
```

It takes an it and returns a `char` at that index or it throws an exception if the index is outside the range.

Comment: so what you are saying is that I was wrong assuming that there are two (2) ways to access the `FromRoom` property. There is only one that requires me to input a Phase as an index argument like so: `famInst.FromRoom[phase]`. Why is there two of them listed in the docs? It confused me.

Comment: no you are right. One of them is a property which returns `Room`. The other is an indexer which takes 'Phase' and returns a `Room`. In my code, I showed you how to access the one that takes a `Phase`

Comment: any ideas on how I can call the other one? Because it only allows me to call the indexer one. I will be happy to award you the answer if you can answer that.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, here are the 2 ways: 1. `Room room = famInst.FromRoom;` 2. `Room room = famInst.FromRoom[somePhase];`

Comment: if you read my question it states that when I call `famInst.FromRoom` it returns a `ReflectedIndexer` the only method that works is when I actually use the second method with the Phase input. Why would it return a reflected indexer? What is that?

Comment: It looks like there is no good answer to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001482/revitapi-ironpython-toroom-returns-indexer-object Apologies.

Comment: @konrad do me a favor: can you please put the cursor on FamilyInstance and go to the definition (F12) and see if both the indexer and property are there?

Comment: @konrad I am not sure what version of the API you are using but I just added a reference to the 2017 NuGet package for RevitAPI and it seems they have fixed the issue. Now there are two: `FromRoom` and `get_FromRoom` (this one is the indexer).

Comment: It works in visual studio but it just won't work for me in the IronPython console that I am using it for (Dynamo). I can live with it. For a moment I thought that the interpreter was confusing the two properties and that there was a way to explicitly tell it which one to use.